# Repeat data in android

Tags: android, repeat

Android app witch connects to a web service in asp website and Gets Data.
the Problem is the I have a repeater an asp which repeats a set of

```
1- image
2- a text
3- text
```

how can I view that in android.

Like Facebook app the post is repeated by changing the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `ListView` with `Custom Adapter`.

Take a look on [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: but can an asp website webservice send Array?<br>

Comment: @MHMazen You can use Json to retrive data